# Get only URI from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have an API - `http://localhost:8080/api/version/<versionA>` where versionA is a Path Parameter.

HttpServletRequest `getRequestURI() returns -> /api/version/<versionA>`

How do we ensure that only `/api/version` is returned back? Is there any way to generalize this for all endpoints and return only the first part of the URI excluding path params?
For example -

```
/api/version/<param1> Should Return /api/version
/api/<param1> Should return /api
/api/version/<param1>/name/<param2> Should return /api/version
```

Comment: Path params are not necessarily at the end of a URL. What would you want /api/<foo>/things/<thingid> to return?

Comment: What is the servlet context path for this servlet, and have you checked what HttpServletRequest call `req.getPathInfo()` returns as it will provide all the path parameters after the registered servlet context path?

Comment: I'll edit the question. But if I have multiple params. I would want only the first part of the URI. 
Ex - /api/version/<param1>/abc/<param2> -> should return /api/version

Answer (score 0):

[Path Parameter](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_PathParam.html#:%7E:text=%40PathParam%20is%20a%20parameter%20annotation,fragments%20into%20your%20method%20call.&text=The%20parameter%20type%20you%20inject,a%20String%20as%20a%20parameter.) is not a Query Parameter; it is rather a part/segment of the URL Path. So, there is no (and there should not be) built-in Servlet API method, that will return your, "custom-sub-stringed" path.

Q: Why?
A: Because you may have more than one path parameters `/a/b/<param1>/<param2>/c/<param3>`

---

> Is there any way to generalize this for all endpoints and return only the first part of the URI excluding path params?

In your case, one option would be to implement some utility method, which will find the the [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) `"/"` and then will return the substring to that last `"/"`.

Comment: I don't want the path till the lastParam, instead the path till the firstParam

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you've constructed things but let's take an example.

```
http://localhost:8080/sample/rest/v1/classLevel/methodLevel/param1/param2/something/param3
```

and a service defined as:

```
@Path("/v1/classLevel")
public class NewService {

    @Path("/methodLevel/{param1}/{param2}/something/{param3}")
    public Response getSomeStuff(@PathParam("param1") String param1,
                                 @PathParam("param2") String param2,
                                 @PathParam("param3") String param3,
                                 @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

This webapp is **deployed under the context root "sample"**.  That means that if I were to go to `http://localhost:8080/sample/` I'd get the root element (perhaps index.html) for the webapp.  In my Application I have:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

So the parameters in the URL are:

1. `request.getServletPath()` returns "/rest"
2. `request.getContextPath()` returns "/sample"
3. `request.getPathInfo()` returns "/v1/classLevel/methodLevel/param1/param2/something/param3"

So I believe that what you want is `request.getContextPath() + request.getServletPath()`.  But it's a bit unclear which part you really need.

**EDIT**
To find out what path is at the class level a little reflection is needed.  Within a class that is being called (i.e. non-static methods of the `NewService` class above) you would be able to get that with:

```
public String getClassLevelPath() {
    if( this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {
        Path annotation = this.getClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
        return annotation.value();
    }

    return null;
}
```

As my class is defined, this returns "/v1/classLevel".  I would personally cache this in something like a static variable as it's not going to change during runtime unless you're doing something else to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This makes a lot more sense!. Based on the example mentioned above, is there a way to get the path at classLevel? Ex - /rest/sample/v1/classLevel ?